# How to solve missing dependency - node js, docker, jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, docker

This to me sounds disjointed, for which I apologies. I really would appreciate help, however.

I am trying to containerise a simple website / api / database. javascript, node js, mongodb.

Everything worked OK until I decided to add a couple of new dependencies in, namely jsonwebtoken and bcryptjs

The current state is :
I have run npm install jsonwebtoken --save and npm install bcryptjs --save in the root directory of the project.
They are both in the package.json dependencies

I am using nodemon to restart upon save within visual studio code. Saving anything does show a restart in the console however the errors remain. I have also "down" and "up" the docker-composer via the command line. I have quit and restarted docker completely, still the error.

Is there something basic that I am missing in the process for adding new dependancies to an existing project?

Following is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=db
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB 
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ./wait-for.sh db:27017 -- /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js
  db:
    image: mongo:4.1.8-xenial
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    volumes:  
      - dbdata:/data/db   
    networks:
      - app-network  
  
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
      
volumes:
  dbdata:
  node_modules:
```

Comment: Can you tell us how is your image being built or share the docker-compose file and the docker-compose up command(any additional parameters etc)? Thanks

Comment: Do you have Compose `volumes:` for your `node_modules` directory?  That tells Docker that directory contains user data that must not be overwritten, and it will take precedence over updates in the image.  Deleting the `volumes:` that overwrite the code in the image should make things work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution, however the work around....
As you can see from my compose file, I run a script on start. I added the npm install commands to this script and ran it. I then remove these commands from the script an re-ran it. All works now.

I am new to docker, so somehow I need to find a way to run this npm install inside the container and this seemed to work. Works, so good enough for now.